# Безопасность SQL запроса Insert

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-injection

Добрый день!
Я начал изучение методов PDO в принципе все понимаю но хотел бы уточнить у знающих людей,в общем мой запрос инсерт

```
DB::insert('table', array(
  'vi' => $vi,
  'data' => '',
  'posi' => $_POST['na'],
  'desc' => $_POST['des'],
  'bu' => $_POST['zana'],
  'ed' => $_POST['kv'],
  'dat' => '$date',
  'dop' => $_POST['dop_i'],
  'priemt' => $_POST['pr'],
  'spisok' => $_POST['spis'],
  'date' => $date1,
  'mesto' => $_POST['mest'],
  'date' => $date,
  'vacan' => '1',
  'con' => $_POST['con']
));
```

На сколько он безопасен в таком виде?
Я пробывал подсовывать вместо значений Плейсхолдеры %i  %l  %s  но выдает ошибку. Я понял что в таком Инсерте Плейсхолдеры не будут работать а вот какой риск у данного запроса что есть угроза SQL инъекций и XSS

Comment: Это не запрос insert. Это вызов статического метода insert пользовательского класса DB. Необходимо смотреть код этого класса.

Comment: Хорошо метод insert  в таком виде безопасен ?  Препарировать я не могу не позволяет конфигурация.

Comment: Нельзя ответить без кода этого класса

Comment: Это невозможно сказать не увидив код метода. раз начинает выдавать ошибки, вероятно он криво написан и его надо переделывать. по данному куску даже невозможно сказать используется внутри pdo или что то другое

Comment: Я использую пользовательский Класс [Meekrodb](https://github.com/SergeyTsalkov/meekrodb/blob/master/db.class.php)

Comment: К PDO этот класс не имеет ни какого отношения.

Comment: А причем тут PDO ? meekrodb это какая то левая библиотека для работы с БД. использует mysqli и при этом не использует bind_param. без которого безопасность гарантировать нельзя. глубоко анализировать этот код ломает. если интересно, расставьте в нем печать выполняемых запросов прямо перед отправкой в БД и смотрите что он там нагенерил

Comment: Напечатал посмотрел, обычный Array выдал мне .В самом запросе стоит плейсхолдер с этого класса.   А где можно раздобыть класс с bind_param
только в гугл не посылайте)

Comment: Хм. вы же пишите "_начал изучение методов PDO_". так почему же вы не используете сам PDO, а ищите какую то библиотеку. Так бы писали "хочу найти какую то библиотеку и изучить её" и к работе PDO это не будет иметь никакого отношения

Comment: phpinfo мне выдал
**Additional .ini files parsed /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mssql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_dblib.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/imagick.ini** Я могу с такими конфигами использовать полноценно PDO

Comment: можешь использовать

Comment: Всем спасибо мне в итоге помогла библиотека от [Colshrapnel] (https://github.com/colshrapnel/thebestpdowrapper) 
И как я полагаю если у меня все запросы будут **prepare** то нет смысла от плейсхолдеров

Comment: Ты все опять перепутал. Prepare сам по себе бесполезен. Он не может взять и волшебным методом обезопасить твой запрос. он как раз и работает только в паре с плейсхолдерами.

Comment: так в нем есть плейсхолдер дефолтный " ? "   я имел введу типа %i  %s    такие плейсхолдеры под тип данных. Они же уже не нужны если мой метод **prepare**   уже содержит " ? "  Или этого недостаточно и мне нужны плейсхолдеры разного формата ?

Comment: Ну со временем ты поймешь, что нужны. Но вместо базовых %i %s дефолтный ? подойдет отлично.

Comment: Значит запрос такого типа если он корректно работает отлично защищен от SQL иньекции--------------------
`$sql2  = "SELECT * FROM pers WHERE name = ? AND id= ?";
 -------------------------- $qwery = DB::prepare($sql2)->execute([Doe,2])->fetch();
 echo '<p>'.$qwery['stname'].'</p>';`

Comment: Да, защищен на 100%.